# Is it possible to change the style of the "Browse" button in the file upload html control?

Tags: html, file-upload, css

I've been looking all over Google for an easy, clean way to change the style of the Browse button of the HTML `<input type=file>` control, but all solutions I've found so far involve hidden controls, absolute positioning of images, jQuery plugins etc. Is there a way to accomplish this using CSS2 that I've missed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How apply CSS to browse button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4365431/how-apply-css-to-browse-button)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry, this is completely browser-dependant.

Take a look at the question [How to rename HTML browse button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163667/how-to-rename-html-browse-button), the same reasons apply.

Answer (score 2):

I have not seen this getting done in pure css (if anyone knows let me know). Well here is something that you might find interesting:

http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/showtopic15621.htm

Mostly used CSS, little bit of javascript too.

Answer (score 1):

No, you didn't miss anything. Its not possible doing this only with CSS.