# customising asp.net fileupload control

Tags: asp.net, file-upload

Using the asp.net file upload control is very easy, i'm trying to squeeze it into my site and the dam thing is  very ugly!.  Can I not change the browse button to an image of my choosing ?

So far i'm failing to achieve this seemingly simple goal. Any ideas on this one ?

Thanks

Comment: You may want to read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163667/how-to-rename-html-browse-button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do much with as it's really down to the browser how it is styled and functions. Just try it in Safari & IE to see the difference.

I have seen sites where people have used overlays to make it look different, kind of giving it a mask.

Here's a more thorough discussion on quirks mode about the problem: [Styling an input type="file"](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)