# Change default text in input type="file"?

Tags: html, file, input, default-value

I want to change default text on button that is "`Choose File`" when we use `input="file"`.

[image]

How can I do this? Also as you can see in image button is on left side of text. How can I put it on right side of text?

Comment: There is option to get this text to variable?

Comment: Answer by ParPar over here is probably what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename HTML "browse" button of an input type=file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163667/how-to-rename-html-browse-button-of-an-input-type-file) for the text part, for style in general: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button

Comment: Try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30275263/1657573

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the button text of <input type="file" />?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file)

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Each browser has it's own rendition of the  control and as such you can't change either the text or the orientation of the control.

There are some "kind of" hacks you may want to try if you want an [html](/questions/tagged/html)/[css](/questions/tagged/css) solution rather than a Flash or [silverlight](/questions/tagged/silverlight)solution.

http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

http://www.shauninman.com/archive/2007/09/10/styling_file_inputs_with_css_and_the_dom

Personally, because most users stick to their browser of choice, and therefore are probably used to seeing the control in the default rendition, they'd probably get confused if they saw something different (depending on the types of users you're dealing with).

Answer (score 292):

Use the [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label#attr-for) attribute of `label` for `input`.

```html
<div>
  <label for="files" class="btn">Select Image</label>
  <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
</div>
```

##### Below is the code to fetch name of the uploaded file

---

```js
$("#files").change(function() {
  filename = this.files[0].name;
  console.log(filename);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <label for="files" class="btn">Select Image</label>
    <input id="files" style="visibility:hidden;" type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: `display:none` can be used on INPUT so it won't use not needed space.

Comment: Works fine on Mac with Chrome, FF and Safari. If it does it also on IE then this is the best and simplest option to style the file input button. Thanks!

Comment: works well, only slight negative is that the user can't see the name of the file that has been selected upon selection.

Comment: Superb ! Is there a way I can get the uploaded file name too by this method?

Comment: @Mike Updated the post to fetch filename

Comment: I couldn't make this work even if my life depended upon it. The filename appears no where. I am using Chrome.

Comment: Wow this is superb! Since I store the files in local state i don't ever need to show then input so this is an amazing solution for me.

Comment: We are using this approach, apparently the most widely used in Angular. However it introduces a bug in accessibility, it can not be accessed via tab nor selected a file upon enter.

Comment: This is the best answer, by just hiding the file, solved the headache that for so long I was thinking about how to get rid of annoyed "choose file" labe.

Comment: Unfortunately, your solution is just a clickable label and not a real button to click on with customized text.

Answer (score 95):

#### I think this is what you want:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button style="display:block;width:120px; height:30px;" onclick="document.getElementById('getFile').click()">Your text here</button>
  <input type='file' id="getFile" style="display:none">
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: best solution here so far.

Comment: This also handles keyboard navigation. To make it perfect, use  `tabindex="-1"` on the hidden file input to skip it while tabbing.

Comment: One thing to note here: If the <button> is inside a <form> , that button will be treated as the "submit" button. This may not be the desired behavior!. To resolve this just add type attribute to the button `<button type="button">`

Answer (score 37):

This might help someone in the future, you can style the label for the input as you like and put anything you want inside it and hide the input with display none.

It works perfectly on cordova with iOS

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ratchet/2.0.2/css/ratchet.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<label for="imageUpload" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-outlined">Seleccionar imagenes</label>
<input type="file" id="imageUpload" accept="image/*" style="display: none">
```

Answer (score 22):

To achieve this, the default input button must be hidden using `display:none` CSS property and a new button element is added to replace it, so we can customize as we wish.

### With Bootstrap

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 
Optional text here 

<label for="inputField" class="btn btn-info">Try me</label>
<input type="file" id="inputField" style="display:none">
```

### With jQuery

In this case the `onclick` attribute added to the button element is indicating to JavaScript to click on the hidden default input button whenever the visible button is clicked.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Optional text here 

<button style="cursor:pointer" onclick="$('#inputField').click()">Click me</button>
<input type="file" id="inputField" style="display:none">
```

### Plain JavaScript with event listener

```js
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', () => { 
  document.getElementById('inputField').click();
})
```

```html
Optional text here 
<button style="cursor:pointer" id="btn">Click me</button>
<input type="file" id="inputField" style="display:none">
```

Answer (score 12):

It is not possible. Otherwise you may need to use Silverlight or Flash upload control.

Comment: Which is not possible? Changing text or placing button on right or both?

Comment: I upvoted this, because I think it's unfair to downvote this answer.  It's basically impossible to change the text of the native file input button.  The "possible solutions" are all hacks or workarounds.

Comment: @PeterLee - Hacks *are* solutions, some even follows the W3C spec.

Answer (score 9):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
 $('#choose-file').change(function () {
  var i = $(this).prev('label').clone();
  var file = $('#choose-file')[0].files[0].name;
  $(this).prev('label').text(file);
 }); 
 });
```

```css
.custom-file-upload{
  background: #f7f7f7; 
  padding: 8px;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3; 
  border-radius: 5px; 
  border: 1px solid #ccc; 
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
can you try this

<label for="choose-file" class="custom-file-upload" id="choose-file-label">
   Upload Document
</label>
<input name="uploadDocument" type="file" id="choose-file" 
   accept=".jpg,.jpeg,.pdf,doc,docx,application/msword,.png" style="display: none;" />
```

Answer (score 4):

The trick is to trigger a click event on click of the file input and manage the visibility of the default input file via CSS. Here's how you can do it:

**jQuery:**

```js
$(function() {
  $("#labelfile").click(function() {
    $("#imageupl").trigger('click');
  });
})
```

**css**

```
.file {
  position: absolute;
  clip: rect(0px, 0px, 0px, 0px);
  display: block;
}

.labelfile {
  color: #333;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  white-space: nowrap;
  padding: 6px 8px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.42857143;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
```

**HTML code:**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <input name="imageupl" type="file" id="imageupl" class="file" />
  <label class="labelfile" id="labelfile"><i class="icon-download-alt"></i> Browse File</label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

Update 2017:

I have done research on how this could be achieved. And the best explanation/tutorial is here:
https://tympanus.net/codrops/2015/09/15/styling-customizing-file-inputs-smart-way/

I'll write summary here just in case it becomes unavailable. So you should have HTML:

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" class="inputfile" />
<label for="file">Choose a file</label>
```

Then hide the input with CSS:

```
.inputfile {
width: 0.1px;
height: 0.1px;
opacity: 0;
overflow: hidden;
position: absolute;
z-index: -1;}
```

Then style the label:

```
.inputfile + label {
font-size: 1.25em;
font-weight: 700;
color: white;
background-color: black;
display: inline-block;
}
```

Then optionally you can add JS to display the name of the file:

```
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll( '.inputfile' );
Array.prototype.forEach.call( inputs, function( input )
{
var label    = input.nextElementSibling,
    labelVal = label.innerHTML;

input.addEventListener( 'change', function( e )
{
    var fileName = '';
    if( this.files && this.files.length > 1 )
        fileName = ( this.getAttribute( 'data-multiple-caption' ) || '' ).replace( '{count}', this.files.length );
    else
        fileName = e.target.value.split( '\\' ).pop();

    if( fileName )
        label.querySelector( 'span' ).innerHTML = fileName;
    else
        label.innerHTML = labelVal;
});
});
```

But really just read the tutorial and download the demo, it's really good.

Answer (score 4):

You can use this approach, it works even if a lot of files inputs.

```js
const fileBlocks = document.querySelectorAll('.file-block')
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-select-file')

;[...buttons].forEach(function (btn) {
  btn.onclick = function () {
    btn.parentElement.querySelector('input[type="file"]').click()
  }
})

;[...fileBlocks].forEach(function (block) {
  block.querySelector('input[type="file"]').onchange = function () {
    const filename = this.files[0].name

    block.querySelector('.btn-select-file').textContent = 'File selected: ' + filename
  }
})
```

```css
.btn-select-file {
  border-radius: 20px;
}

input[type="file"] {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file-block">
  <button class="btn-select-file">Select Image 1</button>
  <input type="file">
</div>
<br>
<div class="file-block">
  <button class="btn-select-file">Select Image 2</button>
  <input type="file">
</div>
```

Comment: I like this approach, but for me Selected File text not showing up, any idea what is the issue. I am google chrome

Answer (score 3):

This should work:

```js
input.*className*::-webkit-file-upload-button {
  *style content..*
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using Bootstrap you can do this thing like the below code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <style>
    .btn-file {
      position: relative;
      overflow: hidden;
    }

    .btn-file input[type=file] {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      min-width: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      font-size: 100px;
      text-align: right;
      filter: alpha(opacity=0);
      opacity: 0;
      outline: none;
      background: white;
      cursor: inherit;
      display: block;
    }

  </style>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <span class="btn btn-file">Upload image from here<input type="file">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This code does not print back to the web page what file was chosen.

Answer (score 3):

I made a script and published it at GitHub: get **[selectFile.js](https://github.com/thielicious/selectFile.js)**
Easy to use, feel free to clone.

**HTML**

```
<input type=file hidden id=choose name=choose>
<input type=button onClick=getFile.simulate() value=getFile>
<label id=selected>Nothing selected</label>
```

**JS**

```
var getFile = new selectFile;
getFile.targets('choose','selected');
```

**DEMO**

**[jsfiddle.net/Thielicious/4oxmsy49/](https://jsfiddle.net/Thielicious/4oxmsy49/)**

Comment: That's good, **but** your code doesn't work when we need more than one input

Comment: @mehmet The OP did not ask for a solution with multiple file inputs.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how its done with bootstrap, only u should put the original input somewhere...idk 
in head and delete the < br > if you have it, because its only hidden and its taking space anyway :)

```html
 <head> 
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
 </head>
 
 <label for="file" button type="file" name="image" class="btn btn-secondary">Secondary</button> </label>
    
 <input type="file" id="file" name="image" value="Prebrskaj" style="visibility:hidden;">
 
 
 <footer>
 
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 
 </footer>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>

<body>
  <button style="display:block;width:120px; height:30px;" onclick="document.getElementById('getFile').click()">Your text here</button>
  <input type='file' id="getFile" style="display:none">
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution...

HTML :

```
<input type="file" id="uploadImages" style="display:none;" multiple>

<input type="button" id="callUploadImages" value="Select">
<input type="button" id="uploadImagesInfo" value="0 file(s)." disabled>
<input type="button" id="uploadProductImages" value="Upload">
```

Jquery:

```
$('#callUploadImages').click(function(){

    $('#uploadImages').click();
});

$('#uploadImages').change(function(){

    var uploadImages = $(this);
    $('#uploadImagesInfo').val(uploadImages[0].files.length+" file(s).");
});
```

This is just evil :D

Answer (score 2):

I build a script that can be easier to do that.

For example:

> `<input data-com="fileBtn" placeholder="Select Image">`

basically, my script is very similar to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43509579/9935654)

### Code

*Pure javascript, no dependencies needed*

```html
<!-- bootstrap.min.css not necessary -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<input data-com="fileBtn" placeholder="Select Image"> <!-- com: components -->
<input data-com="fileBtn" placeholder="Select File">
<div class="mt-2">
<input id="build-by-myself" placeholder="Select Video" accept="video/mp4, video/webm">
<div>

<script>
  //  Test
  (()=>{
    window.onload = () =>{
      // FileButton.className ="btn btn-danger"
      FileButton.BuildAll() // auto build all data-com="fileBtn"
      
      // or you can specify the target that you wanted.
      new FileButton(document.getElementById("build-by-myself"), "btn btn-danger")
    }
  })()

  //  script begin
  class FileButton {
    static className = "btn btn-primary"
    static BuildAll() {
      document.querySelectorAll(`input[data-com="fileBtn"]`).forEach(input=>{
        new FileButton(input, FileButton.className)
      })
    }
    /**
     * @param {HTMLInputElement} input
     * @param {string} btnClsName
     * */
    constructor(input, btnClsName) {
      input.style.display = "none" // [display is better than visibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48495293/9935654)
      input.type = "file"
      const frag = document.createRange().createContextualFragment(`<button class="${btnClsName}">${input.placeholder}</button>`)
      const button = frag.querySelector(`button`)

      input.parentNode.insertBefore(frag, input)

      button.onclick = ()=>{
        input.click()
      }
      input.addEventListener(`change`, (e)=>{
        // create a textNode to show the file name.
        const file = input.files[0]
        if (file === undefined) {
          return
        }
        const textNode = document.createTextNode(file.name)
        if (button.textNode) { // create a new attribute to record previous data.
          button.textNode.remove()
        }
        button.textNode = textNode
        button.parentNode.insertBefore(textNode, input)
      })
    }
  }
</script>
```

### Reference

- [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/133051/9935654)
- [data-*](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_data-.asp)

Comment: Definitely the best solution

Answer (score 1):

Below is an example of a stylized upload button that will read an image, compress it, and download the resulting image. It works by hiding the actual input element, and then through some trickery we make it so that when you click on our fake file uploader it uses the actual input element to pop up the window for choosing a file. By using this method we get 100% control over how the file uploader looks since we are using our own element instead of styling the file upload menu. It also makes it easy to add drag and drop functionality in the future if we ever want to do that.

And then I actually created [a series of blog posts](http://mrme.me/lio/blog/) about this file upload button.

```js
'use strict'
  
var AMOUNT = 10
var WIDTH = 600
var HEIGHT = 400
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas')
canvas.width = WIDTH
canvas.height = HEIGHT

//here's how I created the clickable area
//user clicks the clickable area > we send a click event
//to the file opener > the file opener clicks on the open
//file button > the open file dialogue pops up

function clickableAreaListener(e){
  let clickEvent = new CustomEvent("click",{"from":"fileOpenerHandler"});
  document.getElementById("fileOpener").dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
}
function fileOpenerListener(e) {
  document.getElementById("file-btn").click();
  e.preventDefault();
}

function fileSelectedListener(e){
    readFiles(e.target.files);
}

document.getElementById('file-btn').addEventListener('change', fileSelectedListener);
document.getElementById("clickable-area").addEventListener('click', clickableAreaListener);
document.getElementById("fileOpener").addEventListener("click", fileOpenerListener);

function readFiles(files){
  files = [].slice.call(files); //turning files into a normal array

  for (var file of files){
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = createOnLoadHandler(file);
    reader.onerror = fileErrorHandler;
    //there are also reader.onloadstart, reader.onprogress, and reader.onloadend handlers

    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
  }
}
  
function fileErrorHandler(e) {
  switch(e.target.error.code) {
    case e.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
      throw 'Image not found';
      break;
    case e.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
      throw 'Image is not readable';
      break;
    case e.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
      break;
    default:
      throw 'An error occurred while reading the Image';
  };
}

function createOnLoadHandler(file){
  console.log('reading ' + file.name + ' of type ' + file.type) //file.type will be either image/jpeg or image/png
  
  function onLoad(e){
    var data = e.target.result
    display(data);
    var compressedData = compressCanvas(AMOUNT)
    download(compressedData)
  }
  
  return onLoad
}
  
function display(data){
  
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = data;
  
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    context.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
  }

function compressCanvas(){
    return canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg', AMOUNT / 100);
  }

function download(data) {

    function b64toBlob(b64Data, contentType, sliceSize) {
        contentType = contentType || '';
        sliceSize = sliceSize || 512;

        var byteCharacters = atob(b64Data);
        var byteArrays = [];

        for (var offset = 0; offset < byteCharacters.length; offset += sliceSize) {
            var slice = byteCharacters.slice(offset, offset + sliceSize);

            var byteNumbers = new Array(slice.length);
            for (var i = 0; i < slice.length; i++) {
                byteNumbers[i] = slice.charCodeAt(i);
            }

            var byteArray = new Uint8Array(byteNumbers);

            byteArrays.push(byteArray);
        }

        var blob = new Blob(byteArrays, {type: contentType});
        return blob;
    }
    
    var chromeApp = Boolean(chrome && chrome.permissions)
    if (chromeApp){
    
      chrome.fileSystem.chooseEntry({type:'openDirectory'}, function(entry) {
        chrome.fileSystem.getWritableEntry(entry, function(entry) {
          entry.getFile('example.jpg', {create:true}, function(entry) {
            entry.createWriter(function(writer){
              writer.write(b64toBlob(data.slice(23), 'image/jpg'))
            })
          })
        })
      })
    
    } else {
      let a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = data;
      a.download = 'downloadExample.jpg'
      document.body.appendChild(a)
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(a.href);
      a.remove()
  }
    
}
```

```css
.fileInput {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 100px;
}
  
#clickable-area{
  background: #ccc;
  width: 500px;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
  
#clickable-area-text{
  margin: auto;
}

.yellow-button {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: white;
  background: #f1c40f;
  height: 30px;
  width: 120px;
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 22px;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

```html
<div id="clickable-area">
  <a id='fileOpener'> </a>
  <input type="file" class="fileInput" id="file-btn" accept="image/*" multiple/>
  <div class="yellow-button"><span>Shrink Image</span>
  </div><p id="clickable-area-text">( you can click anywhere in here ) &nbsp;</p>
</div>
  
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Stack Overflow limitations seem to prevent the code snippet from actually compressing and downloading the file. The [exact same code here](http://mrme.me/lio/blog/demos/stylized-example.html) shows that the full upload/compress/download process does actually work as intended.

Answer (score 1):

Ok so very simple pure css way of creating your custom input file.

Use labels, but as you know from previous answers, label doesn't invoke onclick 
function in firefox, may be a bug but doesn't matter with the following.

```
<label for="file"  class="custom-file-input"><input type="file"  name="file" class="custom-file-input"></input></label>
```

What you do is style the label to look how you want it to

```
    .custom-file-input {
        color: transparent;/* This is to take away the browser text for file uploading*/
        /* Carry on with the style you want */
        background: url(../img/doc-o.png);
        background-size: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        width: 200px;
        height: 200px;
        cursor: pointer;
        top: 10%;
        right: 15%;
    }
```

now simply hide the actual input button, but you cant set it to to `visability: hidden`

So make in invisible by setting `opacity: 0;`

```
input.custom-file-input {
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;/*set position to be exactly over your input*/
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

now as you might have noticed i have the same class on my label as i do my input field, that is because i want the to both have the same styling, thus where ever you click on the label, you are actually clicking on the invisible input field.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a `button` to trigger the `input`:

```
<button onclick="document.getElementById('fileUpload').click()">Open from File...</button>
<input type="file" id="fileUpload" name="files" style="display:none" />
```

Quick and clean.

Comment: duplicate of the answer of Apr 20, 2017

Answer (score 0):

[With answers from this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082721/how-to-display-selected-file-names-before-uploading-multiple-files-in-struts2), I fixed what many in coments said doesn¨t work for them which is that it's not showing how many files user chose.

```
<label for="uploadedFiles" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary">Choose files</label>
<input type="file" name="postedFiles" id="uploadedFiles" multiple="multiple" hidden onchange="javascript:updateList()" />
<input class="btn btn-primary mt-2 btn-action" type="submit" value="Send" formmethod="post" formaction="@Url.Action("Create")" /><br />
<span id="selected-count">Selected files: 0</span>
<script>
    updateList = function () {
        var input = document.getElementById('uploadedFiles');//list of files user uploaded
        var output = document.getElementById('selected-count');//element displaying count
        output.innerHTML = 'Selected files: ' + input.files.length;
    }
</script>
```

You can easily improve it by showing names of files instead or whatever you wish to do but all I wanted was to inform user that they have already picked files.

Answer (score 0):

### Customize Input Text (without jQuery)

If you want to customize the text of the file selector button, with vanilla JavaScript, here is a snippet:

```js
document.querySelector("#files").onchange = function() {
  const fileName = this.files[0]?.name;
  const label = document.querySelector("label[for=files]");
  label.innerText = fileName ?? "Browse Files";
};
```

```css
label {
  border: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  font-family: 'Helvetica', sans-serif;
  transition: .5s;
}

label:hover {
  background-color: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="input_container">
  <label for="files" class="btn">Browse Files</label>
  <input id="files" style="display:none;" type="file">
</div>
```

I you wanted to style the file selector button, I have a solution for that:
[Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button/70528034#70528034).

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript you can give the input element a 'title' attribute, for example:

`<input type="file" id="upload_photo" title=""onChange={onChangeTextHandle}/>`

Answer (score 0):

**You can't directly modify it due to browser security restrictions**.

But, you can **hide one input** and create your input with the text you need:

***Please do **NOT** use `display: none`. It would not work with it.*

```html
<div>
  <label>
        <span>Choose my file</span>
        <input type="file" hidden  />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Upload your file"
        />
      </label>
</div>
```

```css
label {
     background-color: #f0f0f0;
    width: 300px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 8px 0px 10px 10px;
    background:  #C69F89
 
}
label:hover{
 background: #A6A15E
}

input[type="text"] {
  margin-top: 30px;
  
  padding: 10px 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 0px 4px 4px 0px;
  width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Here is the same example, but with tailwind and React: https://codesandbox.io/p/live/ffb74e3b-3046-46a3-84f5-1cec55b90004

Answer (score -1):

You can use a simple button and hide input file

using jquery and bootstrap :

HTML code

```
<button class="btn btn-white" id="btn-file" type="button"><i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i> Anexar Documento</button>
<input name="shutdown" id="input-file" type="file" class="form-control hidden" accept="application/pdf, image/png, image/jpeg">
```

CSS :

```
.hidden{display:none}
```

JS :

```
$("#btn-file").click(function () {
    $("#input-file").trigger('click');
});

$("#input-file").change(function () {
    var file = $(this)[0].files[0].name;
    $("#btn-file").html('<i class="fa fa-file-pdf"></i> ' + file);
});
```

[image]

Comment: So besides that the JS is Jquery it's a plain duplicate of the answer of Apr 20, 2017