# Change default button name of Browse in ace:FileEntry

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, icefaces, icefaces-3

I am trying to use ace:fileEntry component to upload images to my database but now, I want to change the name of the button "Browse" in my case "Seleccionar archivo" but I don't know where that name is stored.

```
                    <ace:fileEntry id="ImageFileEntry" 
                                    fileEntryListener="#{usuarioBean.sampleListener}" 
                                    useSessionSubdir="true">

                    </ace:fileEntry>
                    <h:commandButton id="submit" value="subir"></h:commandButton>
```

I attached a screenshot

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b817.png

thanks

Answer (score 3):

The `ace:fileEntry` will render an `<input type="file">` element, the text on this button is always defined by your browser/the language of your browser. It is not possible to change it, have a look at this post for more information and some workarounds: [Change default text in input type="file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file)