# How to create MVC 4 @Html.TextBox type="file"?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to add the following field at my form

```
<input type="file" class="input-file" />
```

I create model and describe this field (the last field)

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Web;

 namespace CorePartners_Site2.Models
 {
     public class FeedbackForm
     {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase ProjectInformation { get; set; }
     }
 }
```

and create

```
@Html.TextBox(null, null, new { type="file", @class="input-file" })
```

but it doesnt work, I get some exception.
What's wrong?

Comment: What error? And why you define null value to name attribute? I mean use like this: `@Html.TextBox("ProjectInformation", null, new { type="file", @class="input-file" })`

Comment: yes, I understood now, I create `@Html.TextBox("file", null, new { type="file", @class="input-file" })` and I get `<input class="input-file" id="file" name="file" type="file" value="">` but I dont need id here. How to create the field without id?

Comment: But if you dont use id you cant bind file to model. And one more suggestion, if you use `ProjectInformation` for id, then mvc will bind file to your model automaticly.

Comment: So, I should do that? `@Html.TextBox("ProjectInformation", null, new { type="file", @class="input-file", id="ProjectInformation" })`

Comment: You should define a name property for htmlHelpers. But you can define what you want for id. I say if you define same like your model, it will bind automaticly. If dont, you should specify it in your controller side

Comment: If you want , I can an write example for you with your model?

Comment: yes, please, I'll be cool)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Model

```
public class FeedbackForm
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string Company { get; set; }
    public string AdditionalInformation { get; set; }
    public HttpPostedFileBase ProjectInformation { get; set; }
}
```

View

```
@model FeedbackForm

@Html.TextBox("Name")
@Html.TextBox("Email")
...
@Html.TextBox("ProjectInformation", null, new { type="file", @class="input-file" })

// submit button
```

My recommended view (strongly - typed)

```
@model FeedbackForm

@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Name)
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Email)
...
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.ProjectInformation, null, new { type="file", @class="input-file" })

// submit button
```

Controller

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult FeedbackForm(FeedbackForm model)
{
    // this is your uploaded file
    var file = model.ProjectInformation;
    ...

    return View();
}
```

MVC is using name convention, so if your textbox and model names match, then MVC will bind your inputs to your model.

Comment: Thank u! If my view was created not strongly-typed, I need to create the view again?

Comment: No, just change helpers. Add "-For" suffix to your html helpers, and use lambda expr. like (x => x.someProp) for name specifiying.

Comment: Not working when using ajax $(this).serialize() it return ProjectInformation null

Comment: @EshaGarg, You cannot upload file with ajax. You must use any plug in.

Comment: how can I change the input file button text? now it's set to "Broese..." by default.

Comment: @Katy, there is no setting to change it. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file)

Comment: What type should I use in the database for `HttpPostedFileBase`?

Answer (score 5):

I think you are getting a null because you have not specified the enctype in your form tag.

@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionMethodName", "Controller", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
 {
}

A working example always help.

Visit http://www.mindstick.com/Articles/cf1e1dd9-fdba-4617-94f0-407223574447/?Upload%20File%20in%20Asp.Net%20Mvc%204

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below syntax

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Email, new { @type="file", @class="input-file" })
```

Comment: The `@` in `@type="file"` is unnecessary.

Answer (score 2):

I solved this problem using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("SalvarEvidencia", "Evidencia", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with just using the input tag directly in your view.  You aren't required to use a helper.

```
<input type="file" class="input-file" />
```

Just make sure it's within your BeginForm declaration block.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the name of the field. If you don't want a name, nor a value, it's better to just include the field as is in your form.

It doesn't make sense to use a helper, if there's nothing dynamic about it.

Answer (score -1):

```
  @using (Html.BeginForm("Action_Name", "Controller_Name",FormMethod.Post))
   {
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new {@class = "text_field"})
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Email)
   }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?