# asp.net Razor Pages Image import

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I got the following code in the .cshtml file:

```html
<tr>
   <td class="registerWidth"><b>Image:</b></td>
   <td>
      @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file", accept="image/*" })
      @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.File, "", new { @class = "redColor" })
   </td>
</tr>
```

This is in my ViewModel:

```cs
  public Image File { get; set; }
```

(Image is from System.Drawing)

The problem is, File is null in the Controller every time.

```cs
 public ActionResult Contact(ContactViewModel data)
        {
            var Image = data.File //data.File is null
        }
```

Comment: How are you sending your file to the Controller? Can you show us that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16644639/how-to-create-mvc-4-html-textbox-type-file

Comment: @RahulSharma i am using a viewmodel and in the form i'm using the Html.Beginform("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `ViewModel`, you need to change the type from `Image` to `HttpPostedFileBase`:

```
public HttpPostedFileBase File { get; set; }
```

And your `Controller`:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(ContactViewModel data)
{
   var Image = data.File //data.File is null
}
```

And your `Form` should look like:

```
@Html.Beginform("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" })
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have stated in your comment, you are using `Html.Beginform("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post`

However, can I suggest the following as when posting images to controller methods, it seems to work fine.

```
 @using ("Contact", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new {enctype = "multipart/form-data"})
 {
     // form things blah blah blag

     // When it comes to inputting the image file, I suggest you do the following
     // Instead of this @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.File, new { type = "file", accept="image/*" })

    // Have
    <input type="file" name="file" id="fileUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"/>
 }
```

You controller method would then be the following to reflect these changes.

```
public ActionResult Contact(ContactViewModel model, HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    var Image = file.FileName;
}
```

So what are we doing here?

We are creating a form such as you have done before but we are adding an extra parameter that specifies how the form should be encoded when passing it to the controller.

```
<input type="file" name="file" id="fileUpload" accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"/>
```

Here we are saying that there will be an input called 'file' that can accept png, jpg or jpeg images.

```
HttpPostedFileBase file
```

This is the file that we will be passing. The `name` has to be the exact same name as the `name` in the input tags