# How to change upload button to text?

Tags: html, css, file-upload

I have used upload file (type=file) to upload a file. I want to change the button to text. Since the user will using either Google chrome or IE. So I have to consider both browsers. I would prefer simple code.
Here is my code (I'm using multiple upload files)

```
<td><input type="file" name="picture[]" id="picture" ></td>
```

thanks

Comment: Your question isn't clear. Wouldn't changing the input to `type="text` solve your problem?

Comment: ok can you post your form and tell what exactly you want to change?

Comment: google chrome and IE bother support `type="file"`

Comment: I've edited your tags as I can't see how this would be related to `PHP`, I gather this is a layout / formatting issue, hence `HTML` & `CSS`.

Comment: sorry for making most of you confusing, what i mean is to css the upload button (browse/choose file button) to a text something like 'click to choose file' so when people click on that text it will popup box to choose file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand right, you're asking about styling `input` tags with `type="file"`. This is pretty difficult, but what I usually do is wrap the input, and include another tag that will show the desired style. I then position the input tag on top (so that it can still be clicked), but make it transparent so the underlying style shows through.
Something like:

HTML:

```
<div class="uploadWrapper">
    <p>Click to choose file</p>
    <input type="file" name = "filedata" size="100" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.uploadWrapper {
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
    height: 25px;
    width: 250px;
    background: rgb(10,100,210);
}

.uploadWrapper input {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
    filter: alpha(opacity=0);
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.uploadWrapper p {
    margin: 0 10px;
    position: absolute;
    line-height: 25px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BYossarian/NVr6t/

Answer (score 0):

"Each browser has it's own rendition of the control and as such you can't change either the test or the orientation of the control."
- [Original Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file)

However, I believe you can be a bit tricky and modify the button with CSS.

```
#picture {
    text-decoration: none;
    /*  etc... */
}
```