# HTML/C# - Why my label is in my language?

Tags: c#, html

Why are the upload file label and button in Portuguese (my language) and how do I change them to English?

Here is a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

And here is my code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Memes", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <div>       
        <input type="file" name="file" />
        <button type="submit">Upload</button>
    </div>
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [change language input type=file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517321/change-language-input-type-file)

Comment: Have you added <html lang="en"> to your HTML?