# How can I update the displayed file name in a custom file input component in Shiny?

Tags: jquery, r, shiny

Hope someone can help with this.

I'm building a Shiny application and I'm struggling with a custom file input component I made - it is nothing too fancy, I simply followed the tutorials on the Shiny website and used the default Bootstrap classes. I also added javascript, but since I'm an absolute beginner at this, maybe someone can explain what I'm doing wrong: basically the input works just fine, when clicked a file chooser opens and you're able to select what you want. However when I click ok, the displayed file name should change in the file name I selected, but instead it displays the placeholder.

The HTML for the input:

```
browse_only_fileinput <- function(inputId,
                                  label = NULL,
                                  placeholder = "No file selected",
                                  width = NULL
                                  ) {
  restoredValue <- shiny::restoreInput(id = inputId, default = NULL)

  if (!is.null(restoredValue) && !is.data.frame(restoredValue)) {
    warning("Restored value for ", inputId, " has incorrect format.")
    restoredValue <- NULL
  }

  if (!is.null(restoredValue)) {
    restoredValue <- jsonlite::toJSON(restoredValue, strict_atomic = FALSE)
  }

  inputTag <- tags$input(
    id = inputId,
    name = inputId,
    type = "file",
    `data-restore` = restoredValue,
    class = "form-control",
    placeholder = placeholder
  )

  labelInput <- if (!is.null(label)) {
    tags$label(label,
               class = "form-label browse-only-fi",
               id = paste0(inputId, "-label"),
               `for` = inputId)
  } else {
    NULL
  }

  tagList(
    singleton(
      tags$head(
        tags$script(src = "browse_only_fi.js")
      )
    ),
    div(
      class = "form-group shiny-input-container",
      style = htmltools::css(width = validateCssUnit(width)),
      labelInput,
      inputTag
    )
  )
}
```

And the javascript code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var browseOnlyFileInput = new Shiny.InputBinding();
    $.extend(browseOnlyFileInput, {
      find: function(scope) {
        return $(scope).find(".browse-only-fi");
      },
      getValue: function(el) {
          var file = el.files[0];
          if (file) {
              read = new FileReader();
              read.readAsDataURL(file);
          }
          return read.result;
      },
      setValue: function(el, value) {
        $(el).val(value);
      },
      subscribe: function(el, callback) {
          $(el).on("change.browse-only-fi", function (e) {
              callback();
          });
      },
      unsubscribe: function(el) {
          $(el).off(".browse-only-fi");
      }
    });

    Shiny.inputBindings.register(browseOnlyFileInput);
});
```

[image]

Am I missing something? Thanks in advance

EDIT 1: I just realised that the place holder actually doesn't change even when specifying a different one. Is Bootstrap doing something under the hood?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you're making life unnecessarily complicated.  Doesn't `fileInput("file", "Choose file:", placeholder="No file chosen")` do what you want?  Nothing else in your UI or server, no javascript.  Nothing else.

Comment: I want to change the default fileInput since it has unnecessary elements (like a progress bar) and it is difficult to customize its appearance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The text actually comes from the `<input type = "file">` element and cannot be changed by `JS` or `css` means (Well you could hide the text, but not change it via `css`).

Just check the following plain `HTML` snippet and you will realize that the text next to the button appears there "magically".

```html
<input type="file">
```

This gets even worse when you have a different language setting b/c this text is translated (cf this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20517321/change-language-input-type-file)).

If you look carefully into the `fileInput` code, you will see that the shiny developers used a `<input type = "text">` element for showing the text (I guess for the very same reason).

Bottom line: if you use `<input type="file">` you cannot change the placeholder. If you want ot change it, you have to build the element with different tags (`fileInput` can be a good inspiration)

Comment: Thanks! I was really wandering why it wasn't working, I could go for the same approach of Shiny devs maybe