# How to display selected file names before uploading multiple files in Struts2?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, file-upload, struts2

I am using Struts2 to upload multiple files:

```
<s:file name="files" multiple="multiple" />
```

When I select multiple files it displays the number of files, eg. 3 files.

The project requirements are that the user should be able to **see what files he selected before uploading**.

Is it possible to display the selected files names in a list or maybe in the control itself ?

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the HTML5 `files` property of the `<input type="file" />` element like follows:

```js
updateList = function() {
    var input = document.getElementById('file');
    var output = document.getElementById('fileList');
    var children = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < input.files.length; ++i) {
        children += '<li>' + input.files.item(i).name + '</li>';
    }
    output.innerHTML = '<ul>'+children+'</ul>';
}
```

```html
<input type="file" multiple
       name="file" 
         id="file" 
   onchange="javascript:updateList()" />

<p>Selected files:</p>

<div id="fileList"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks a ton..it works perfectly awesome :) . And yes it did work with the <s:file> too.

Comment: and if you use asp.net FileUpload, input should be: 
var input = document.getElementById('<%= fileupload.ClientID%>');

Comment: how to get full path of selected file ?

Comment: @Inderjeet, not possible for security reasons!

Comment: @Andrea Ligios <li> is displaying out side <ul>. How to solve this? I need to make the <li> inside <ul>

Comment: @Andrea Ligios Yes it is a CSS definitely, but it is rendering through this script. You can run the code snippet and inspect element. you can see that. <div id="fileList"><ul></ul><li>filename1</li><li>filename2</li></div>

Comment: @Naveenbos you're right, there was an HTML (not CSS) problem. Probably calling `.innerHTML = "<ul>"` resulted in the browser adding the closing tag too... I've edited the script, enjoy it.

Comment: @Andrea Ligios This code is working perfectly. Is it possible to show the image along with the name using this code?

Comment: @Naveenbos, you should really upvote the answer, since it helped... and then open a new question (which, as-is, gets a fat chance of being closed for being a *"gimme the code"* type of question)

Comment: then how to make a remove button there that "removed' the selected file?

Comment: The question is not clear, and it would be better if you ask it as a brand new question