# How to display file names before uploading?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this input field where i can upload multiple files (txt,pdf and doc). What i want is when user chose what files want to upload to display that files bellow. Any suggestion how can i do that?

```
 {!! Form::file('documents[]', ['class' => 'hidden','multiple'=>true]) !!}
```

Comment: Does your form got `enctype="multipart/form-data"` ?

Comment: do you mean that the files should be shown before uploading or after ?

Comment: Similar problem solved already [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26101941)

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code,

```
$file = $request->file('document');

for($i=0;$i<count($file);$i++)
{
    echo "<br> file Name : ".$file->getClientOriginalName();
}
```

this display filename of all available files.