# Capture and display a text from a hidden input

Tags: javascript, html, input

I use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36248168/1354580) to change the button text of `<input type="file" />.` It works, but it have a small drawback - after a file was chosen the user will not see what file was selected, because this info is not displayed (it is hidden with the original button). How to make visible this information without to display the original (hidden) button?

The code:

```
<input type="button" id="loadFileXml" value="loadXml" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" />
<input type="file" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file"/>
```

Comment: You could create a div and populate it with info from the `files` property in the input: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082721/how-to-display-selected-file-names-before-uploading-multiple-files-in-struts2

Comment: @lurie check the answer. let me know if you expected anything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `span` with no text in it and then `update` its value to the value of your `input` type of file. Something like

```js
function showFileName(){
document.getElementById("fileName").innerHTML = document.getElementById("file").files[0].name

}
```

```html
<input type="button" id="loadFileXml" value="loadXml" onclick="document.getElementById('file').click();" />
<span id="fileName"></span>
<input type="file" onChange="showFileName()" style="display:none;" id="file" name="file"/>
```

Comment: This works. The only problem is a "C:\fakepath\" part before the selected file name. I work in Ubuntu, so I don't know what will be displayed in a Windows system. Can be retained only the file name (with extension)?

Comment: this will be the same in both environments. Anyways, I've edited the code to print the file name only.

Comment: @lurie, please accept and upvote the answer if it resolved your query

Comment: Glad to know that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a placeholder element under your visible input:

```
<p id="file_path"></p>
```

Then (I used `jQuery` for this part), events side:

```
​$('#file').change
(
    function(e)
    {
        $('#file_path').text(e.target.files[0]);
    }
);​​​
```

Comment: I can't make it to work. I get this message in the Developer Tools Console: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token`.

Comment: Sorry, I fixed :O