# Remove path from output js

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what i have. the out put i get is C./FAKE PATH/(value).          I just want it to show the value not the C./FAKE PATH/.

```
$('#inputid').change(function(){
  var value =$(this).val();
alert(value);
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display selected file names before uploading multiple files in Struts2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26082721/how-to-display-selected-file-names-before-uploading-multiple-files-in-struts2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `split('/').pop()` to get anything after the last `/`.

E.G:

```
$('#inputid').change(function(){
    var value = $(this).val().split('/').pop();
    alert(value);
})
```

Comment: I'm still getting the same output

Comment: What's the output you get from the alert?