# Display the Name of the File in File Upload Button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Here is my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/08ej5n1a/1/)

This is my Css:

```
label input[type="file"] 
{
display: block;
margin-top: -20px;
opacity: 0;
}
```

Here i have only the text instead of File Upload Button (As i given opacity:0)

How can i display the File Name that is chosen

Note : I just want to display the File Name near the upload text

Comment: not sure if you can, I think the browser blocks acces to the file totally due to security. I may and frequently am wrong though

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change default text in input type="file"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is just to set the value of tag to the current value of the file input by adding this to your onchange event:

```js
document.getElementById('spanFileName').innerHTML = this.value
```

As you can see in the full example:

```html
Upload File: 
<input type="file" onchange=" document.getElementById('spanFileName').innerHTML = this.value; imagechangesupplier(this,57);" style="display:block;margin-top: -20px;opacity: 0;" >
<br />
<br />
File Selected: <span id='spanFileName'></span>
```

One thing you need to take note of is that using this method always produces the name of the file and adds 'c:/fakepath/' as a prefix. You can just replace the text to give you the file name.

Comment: I am already using onchange even for some other action, Is there any possiblity to have it too ??

Comment: If you check the example, you'll see your code is included.

onchange=" 
document.getElementById('spanFileName').innerHTML = this.value;
imagechangesupplier(this,57);
"

Comment: Alternatively, you can just add:

document.getElementById('spanFileName').innerHTML = this.value;

in the imagechangesupplier function.

Answer (score 0):

File API [depends](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi) on particular browser.

```
if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
  //  File APIs are supported.
} else {
  alert('The File APIs are not fully supported in this browser.');
}
```

Here is an working example - http://jsfiddle.net/g23ytpby/.

Answer (score 0):

Here is [**`JSFiddle Link`**](http://jsfiddle.net/Varun_Chakervarti/n2crv7qm/), Check this out !!

It displays **File Name** that is chosen near the upload text.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of **files property** in **FileListObject** you can display the name of the file, size of file which are ready to upload.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>FileName</title>
    <style>
        input {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="file" multiple="multiple" id="file" onchange="showFileName()">
    <p id="filename"></p>
    <script>
        var x = document.getElementById('file');
        var filename = document.getElementById('filename');

        function showFileName() {
                for (var i = 0; i < x.files.length; i++) {
                    var file = x.files[i];
                    filename.innerHTML = file.name;
                }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```