# How can i change the default text of my input type="file"?

Tags: html

I need to change / remove the default text tag form my upload button.

Here i need to remove "Keine Datei ausgewählt"

[image]

How can I do it?

Thx for your help

Comment: please you can post your code or fiddle , snippet etc.?

Comment: i just have a normal input tag with the type file and an ID @Jainam

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<button>My button</button>
```

or

```
<input type="button" value="my button">
```

or you may use [bootstrap buttons](http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_buttons.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Without posting code I guess you need to change something there :

```
<button type="submit">Your changes</button>
```

Comment: I dont mean the text thats on the button, i mean the text next to my button (see picture)

Comment: You should post your code next time so it will be easier to check exactly where your changes need to be made

Comment: can you help me get my asking right back. i got banned from asking cuz i didnt know how to ask and how to programm back then when i asked this. you would really help me with a upvote <3

Answer (score 0):

I have not much reputation that's why i am writing this an answer your question is possible duplicate of

[Change default text in input type="file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file)

you can check the link.