# How to insert text into <input type="file"/>

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have problem to insert simple text inside `<input type="file"/>`. In my case input type is bordered and with Upload function. When i try to insert text inside i loose upload function in the bordered field where i hide "Browse" button behind. here is my code...

```
<div class="col-md-12 background">
    <div class="file_button_container">
      <input type="file"/>
      <div class="k-span text-center">
        <span> Click here to upload image </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: What output do you want?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33822113/5291509 this is the simplest way, i think

Answer (score 0):

Each browsers have their own specific settings for the upload button. Therefore you cannot change the text nor the function of that button.

There are some plugins you can find to hack that.