# Remove "choose file" from input

Tags: html, css

I could not figure out how to remove the "choose file" from the input button. I just want the user to be able to drag or upload the file directly by clicking on the image. This is what I have so far : [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T9GWk.png)

```html
<div class="popup-wrapper popup-wrapper-3">
  <div class="popup">
    <div class="popup-close">x</div>
    <div class="popup-content">
      <h2>Upload Your Resume</h2>
      <p class="small-text">Upload your resume to complete the job application
      </p>
      <p class="sub">
        <label>Resume:</label>
        <input accept=".doc, .docx, .pdf" type="file" display="none" placeholder="" name="resume">
        <img src="../images/search/apply.gif">
        <p class="small-text">Click to browse the file
        </p>
        <button class="button vlose-button" type="button">Apply Now</button>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!
Have you tried with other browsers? 
FireFox doesn't show that message.

Another thing (maybe more important), the `input type="file"` doesn't have placeholder attribute, and there is no "display" attribute. 
If you want to use custom attributes you should use the [data-*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) structure.
If you want to style it (i.e hide the input) you should do that with CSS.

You can read more about this [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file).

Hope that will point you to the right direction and Good luck!