# How can i set choose profile image input on right side of input with label instead of "choose file" ->'choose image'

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4

i am creating teacher form i want to choose images from gallery for profile , i want to change label and position of "choose image button " on the right side with label of "Choose Image" &  label in same input box on left side "please select  profile picture " i am using angular and bootstrap 4

> This is html

```
                  <div class="form-group ">
                    <p class="input-group">
                        <i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                        <label for="file">Choose file to upload</label>
                        <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/* "  class="form-control">
                     </p> 
                   </div>
```

> This is Css.

```
.form-control{
    background: #000;
    color: beige;
}
```

Comment: You can't change that text, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file . Btw, you are missing _id="file"_ on your input.

Answer (score 0):

```
  <div class="form-group ">
    <p class="input-group">
        <i class="fa fa-camera fa-2x  user-icon fa-fw" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        <label for="file" class="col-sm-10 form-control">Choose file to upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/* "  class="col-sm-2 form-control">
     </p> 
   </div>
```

Please try this way. Hope this will help you.. :)

Comment: Thanks Pranav MS this is answer or half of my question . Can i change text of "choose file " choose image ?