# How can I change the Text on a upload button?

Tags: javascript

I have got this

```
    <div class="offset-sm-6 col-sm-6 offset-md-8 col-md-4">
        <g:uploadForm controller="employeeWorkingHours" action="importFile">
            <div class="custom-file">
                <input type="file" name="file" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile" onchange="form.submit();showLoader('.custom-file')">
                <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile"><g:message code="dateimport.upload.label"/></label>
            </div>
        </g:uploadForm>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fIzQ.png)
and I have got a button with the text "browse" on it and I can not get rid of that text on that button.
Any tips? Thanks

Comment: here you go: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5139316/12576990

Comment: There are probably more duplicates.  Basically what you're looking to do is customize the `<input type="file">`, which is likely best done by hiding it and using custom elements and code to interact with it.  There are a variety of JavaScript plugins you can use, depending on what frameworks you may be using.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have a similar problem somewhere else, where I have to change the text in that button and not only hide the visibility.