# How to change the default design for input type=“file” in reactjs?

Tags: css, reactjs, input, tailwind-css

I'm trying to make a field so that the user can select and upload their file.

I have already written a simple code to select a file.

```
 export const UploadFile = () => {
  return (
      <input type="file" id="fileUpload" onChange={uploadFile} />

};
```

Before choose:
[image]

After choose:
[image]

However, I would like to add some styling to this component. And since I'm using **input** I'm running into difficulties.

At the moment I am using the following code for the design

```
        <div className="justify-between">
          <span>
            C:\example\Users\user\someVideo\
          </span>
          <button type="button">
            choose file
          </button>
        </div>
```

[image]

So my question is, tell me how can I integrate the first part of the code with the second

Comment: I usually spread the input out over it, and set its opacity to 0. If you want to, you can even make your button click the input when it gets clicked. And when the change event occurs, you change the text. Or you hook up a temporary input to the button and click that in the background or something.

Comment: The best approach would be to have a custom label element with a for attribute attached to a hidden file input element. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button

Comment: How is react relevant?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Styling an input type="file" button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What i did in a recent project is continued using the input and target the file-selector-button of the input to style the button. heres a quick [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/determined-kate-zrrq9t?file=%2Fsrc%2Fstyles.css%3A31%2C2)
where i style a file input

here's the basic idea in the css i did

```
#attachment::file-selector-button {
  background-color: #48bb78;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0.375rem 0.375rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

attachment is the id of the file input

Note: i left the styles from my project so change as needed

EDIT:
to have the button on the right just change this

```
#attachment::file-selector-button {
  float: right; 
  background-color: #48bb78;
  border: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 0 0.375rem 0.375rem 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

adding the float right will move the button and the margin 0 is needed to move it till the end, after doing this you will need to change some of the other styles to match the reversed order

Comment: Could you help me with my example, given that my button is on the right and the file name is on the left (as in the code). And I would be very grateful if you used tailwind

Comment: Thank you. I will sort this out. Can you tell me how I can change the text on the button?

Comment: @Paul Please don't ask follow up questions as comments. Ask them as new questions. But remember to search first https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5138719/change-default-text-in-input-type-file