# How to rename the upload file button

Tags: html, css

How to rename the upload file button.
I know how to style it, but rename the button is how?.

```
<input type="file" />
```

Thanks for the answer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to rename HTML "browse" button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163667/how-to-rename-html-browse-button)

Comment: http://asp-net-example.blogspot.in/2009/01/aspnet-fileupload-example-how-to-rename.html

Answer (score 4):

Not possible, but with a hack you can do it.

Eventhough you haven't tagged `jQuery` or `Javascript`, here I would like to present my idea using jQuery.

**HTML:**

```
<button id="hackIt">Upload</button>
<input type="file" />
```

**CSS:**

```
input[type='file'] {
    display: none;
}
```

**JS:**

```
$('#hackIt').on('click', function(){
$('input[type=file]').trigger('click');
});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/9e85W/)

Answer (score 1):

You can change it by using something like value="Upload"

Answer (score 0):

there is no way u can change it you should use css hacks or javascript to create custom file button design

Answer (score 0):

Well, the short answer is - you can't! The text is predefined in the browser and is this way for security.

There are many ways to add different styles to the file select button using javascript/css, though. Just google something along the lines `style file input button`. You will most likely have to settle with an image for the button if you want to change the text.

Answer (score 0):

Browse button is dependent on Browser. 
It display in different way in different browser.

You can make custom button to show different view in every browser
Thanks