# PHP submit button default language

Tags: php, forms, button

I am trying to create a multiple file upload on my test site.

My problem is that although I am using English for everything else (register/login form, menus e.t.c), the button of the file upload appears in Greek and I haven't found yet a way to change it.

This is the visual result of the following code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzV66.jpg

**Code:**

```
<?php
    include 'core/init.php';
    admin_protect();
    include 'includes/overall/start.php';
?>

<h1>Multiple file upload:</h1>
<form action="uploads/multipleupload.php" method="post" enctype = "multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
<input type="submit" value="Upload">
</form>

<?php include 'includes/overall/end.php'; ?>
```

Comment: Maybe this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686905/labeling-file-upload-button or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1944267/how-to-change-the-button-text-of-input-type-file will answer your question.

Comment: Or this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163667/how-to-rename-html-browse-button-of-an-input-type-file

Comment: Apparently this question is a duplicate.. I am sorry I didn't find the other similar questions while submitting mine..